# Any web service i can use to store small amounts of data (for free)?

Tags: web-services

any web service i can use to store small amounts of data (thinking XML or JSON) for free if possible?

i am thinking i wanna create a small todo app just exploration/learning (so preferably free) that also backups data to the cloud so they can use it on smartphones for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) appears to have an [API](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons).

Comment: oh this maybe what i need. i need to [register for a developer key](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apply) tho. hoping i can get it soon

Comment: Dropbox is overkill for small amounts of data. The OP is talking about kilobytes of data, which are definitely the wrong way to use dropbox.

Comment: @paul, but is there a better service more appropriate for this? **UPDATE: ** ok i saw ur answer. Google Apps

Answer (score 3):

Google's app engine is free for low-volume use, and includes some amount of storage. If you get really popular, you can scale up easily.

More info here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/

The documentation on what is available for free is here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html

In a nutshell, if you serve fewer than 5 million pageviews a month, you are unlikely to run out of free processing power.

Comment: hmm i looked at that just now, but don't see that its free?

Comment: It's free for small amounts of data and processing power, where small is far greater than you're likely to use for an example project.

Comment: hmm thats good to know, i still need a domain name, plus i learnt java but kind of prefer C#, python seems like a good alternative but i didn't learn it yet. i guess i can get started learning google apps first. or use the DropBox alternative. [Google Apps Standard Edition](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html)

Comment: App engine works with Java and Python. We're not talking about Google apps. You are confused. http://code.google.com/appengine/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Dropbox is accepting applications for API access](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/05/dropbox-api-lets-you-add-cloud-storage-to-your-apps/).

> Dropbox, the free, web-based file
>   backup service, has rolled out a new
>   API that gives developers a way to
>   access, edit and save any file in a
>   user’s Dropbox account.

I've just signed up.  No mention how long it typically takes to approve access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Amazon S3](https://s3.amazonaws.com/) web services cloud computing infrastructure.

Comment: I think its worth mentioning this isn't free